# Shading joints according to blend index in OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, animation, opengl, glsl

I'm having trouble with a QtWidgets test program to visualize joints in old FVF mesh data, highlighting the user's chosen individual joints.  I have reduced the program and included all parts below.

The program loads a mesh consisting of vertex and element array data, renders it as a white wireframe, but colours all vertices of a specified blend index red. Blend indices are present in the vertex data. They are collected and presented in a list widget. Clicking on an index forwards that index to the fragment shader, which overrides the default colour, white, with red, for vertices with matching blend index.

Here is an example of the program colouring vertices with a blend index of 0:

[image]

The coloured part makes sense as the root of the skeleton.

The problem is that this is only working when the chosen blend index is 0. Selecting any other index results in the wireframe being rendered all white. The expected behaviour is that other parts of the mesh would be coloured red. The vertex data is confirmed correct, as it works in its original application, and is certainly not the source of the error.

I'm unsure how to explore this problem. I have next to no experience in debugging shaders - assuming they are the source of the error. One idea I wondered about is data alignment. Here is the layout of the FVF data in an enum:

**openglwidget.h**:

```
#ifndef OPENGLWIDGET_H
#define OPENGLWIDGET_H

#include <QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QOpenGLVertexArrayObject>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QVector3D>

enum VertexLayout {
    XyzOffset = 0,
    NormalOffset = 12,
    TexcoordOffset = 24,
    TangentOffset = 32,
    BinormalOffset = 44,
    BlendIndexOffset0 = 56,
    BlendWeightOffset0 = 57,
    BlendIndexOffset1 = 61,
    BlendIndexWeight1 = 62,
    BlendIndexOffset2 = 66,
    BlendWeightOffset2 = 67,
    Size = 71 // Size in bytes of one raw vertex
};

class OpenGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    OpenGLWidget(QWidget* parent=nullptr);
    ~OpenGLWidget() override;
    void initGeometry(const QByteArray& rawVertices, const QByteArray& rawIndices);
    void setIndex(int index);
    void initializeGL() override;
    void paintGL() override;
    void resizeGL(int w, int y) override;
signals:
    void readyForData();
private:
    void initShaders();
    float aspect = 1.33f;
    qint32 numIndices = 0;
    int blendIndex = 0;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram program;
    QOpenGLVertexArrayObject vao;
    QOpenGLBuffer arrayBuf;
    QOpenGLBuffer indexBuf;
    QVector3D eye, target, up;
};

#endif // OPENGLWIDGET_H
```

While all other attributes are floats, the blend indices are bytes. I specify them in `initGeometry` below with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`:

**openglwidget.cpp**:

```
#include "openglwidget.h"

#include <QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QOpenGLVersionProfile>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>

OpenGLWidget::OpenGLWidget(QWidget* parent)
    :QOpenGLWidget(parent),
     arrayBuf(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer),
     indexBuf(QOpenGLBuffer::IndexBuffer),
     up(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
{
}

OpenGLWidget::~OpenGLWidget()
{
}

void OpenGLWidget::initGeometry(const QByteArray& rawVertices, const QByteArray& rawIndices)
{
    vao.create();
    vao.bind();

    arrayBuf.create();
    indexBuf.create();
    arrayBuf.bind();
    arrayBuf.allocate(rawVertices, rawVertices.size());
    indexBuf.bind();
    indexBuf.allocate(rawIndices, rawIndices.size());

    numIndices = rawIndices.size() / 2; // sizeof(qint16)

    int vertexLocation = program.attributeLocation("a_position");
    program.enableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);
    program.setAttributeBuffer(vertexLocation,
                               GL_FLOAT,
                               VertexLayout::XyzOffset,
                               3,
                               VertexLayout::Size);

    int blend0Location = program.attributeLocation("a_blend0");
    program.enableAttributeArray(blend0Location);
    program.setAttributeBuffer(blend0Location,
                               GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                               VertexLayout::BlendIndexOffset0,
                               1,
                               VertexLayout::Size);

    vao.release();

    update();
}

void OpenGLWidget::setIndex(int index)
{
    if (index != blendIndex) {
        blendIndex = index;
        update();
    }
}

void OpenGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    QOpenGLVersionProfile profile(format);
    auto functions = context()->versionFunctions(profile);
    QOpenGLWidget::initializeGL();
    functions->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    initShaders();
    emit readyForData();
}

void OpenGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE); // simple wireframe
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Hard-coded pose
    QMatrix4x4 mv;
    eye = QVector3D(-1.50f, 2.33f, 1.43f);
    target = QVector3D(0.50f, 0.28f, 0.94f);
    mv.lookAt(eye, target, up);
    QMatrix4x4 mp;
    mp.perspective(75.0f, aspect, 1.0f, 200.0f);
    QMatrix4x4 mm;
    mm.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    program.setUniformValue("mvp_matrix", mp * mv * mm);
    program.setUniformValue("boneToColor", blendIndex);
    vao.bind();
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, nullptr);
}

void OpenGLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    aspect = h == 0 ? 1 : w / h;
}

static const char* vertexShaderSource =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "in vec4 a_position;\n"
    "in int a_blend0;\n"
    "flat out int v_blend0;\n"
    "uniform mat4 mvp_matrix;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "gl_Position = mvp_matrix * a_position;\n"
    "v_blend0 = a_blend0;\n"
    "\n}";

static const char* fragmentShaderSource =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "flat in int v_blend0;\n"
    "out vec4 fragmentColor;\n"
    "uniform int boneToColor;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "if (v_blend0 == boneToColor)\n"
    "fragmentColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "else\n"
    "fragmentColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n"
    "\n}";

void OpenGLWidget::initShaders()
{
    if (!program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vertexShaderSource)) {
        qCritical() << "Failed to load vertex shader";
        close();
    }
    if (!program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, fragmentShaderSource)) {
        qCritical() << "Failed to load fragment shader";
        close();
    }
    if (!program.link()) {
        qCritical() << "Failed to link program";
        close();
    }
    if (!program.bind()) {
        qCritical() << "Failed to bind program";
        close();
    }
}
```

I understand that GLSL will convert this type to `int`. Perhaps this conversion is the cause of trouble, but if so, I'm unsure how to test it. Perhaps there is some other error in the shaders, but then, the case of `blendIndex == 0` works.

It is worth noting that this mesh associates three blend indices and three blend weights with each vertex. The program only pays attention to the first blend index. I'm too new to this topic to understand yet whether this could cause the problem.

Although this problem is likely due to a lack in my understanding of OpenGL or the underlying data, I have also tagged the question with Qt in case some wrinkle in their OpenGL interface is involved.

Here are the remaining files needed to run the project:

**mainwindow.h**:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class QListWidget;
class QListWidgetItem;
class OpenGLWidget;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget* parent=nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    void loadGeometry();
    void onIndexSelected(QListWidgetItem* item);
    QListWidget* selector;
    OpenGLWidget* openGLWidget;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <set>

#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QListWidget>

#include "openglwidget.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    :QMainWindow(parent),
     selector(new QListWidget(this)),
     openGLWidget(new OpenGLWidget(this))
{
    selector->setFixedWidth(80);
    auto dummy = new QWidget(this);
    auto hbox = new QHBoxLayout(dummy);
    hbox->addWidget(selector);
    hbox->addWidget(openGLWidget);
    setCentralWidget(dummy);
    setMinimumSize(640, 480);

    connect(openGLWidget, &OpenGLWidget::readyForData,
            this, &MainWindow::loadGeometry);
    connect(selector, &QListWidget::itemClicked,
            this, &MainWindow::onIndexSelected);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::onIndexSelected(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    int index = item->text().toInt();
    openGLWidget->setIndex(index);
}

void MainWindow::loadGeometry()
{
    // Read raw geometry from file:
    QFile inf("boneShaderTestGeometry.dat");
    if (!inf.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qCritical() << "Failed to open geometry file";
        return;
    }
    QDataStream ins(&inf);
    ins.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);

    qint32 numVerts;
    ins >> numVerts;
    QByteArray rawVertices(numVerts * VertexLayout::Size, 0);
    ins.readRawData(rawVertices.data(), rawVertices.size());

    qint32 numIndices;
    ins >> numIndices;
    QByteArray rawIndices(numIndices * 2 /* sizeof(qint16) */, 0);
    ins.readRawData(rawIndices.data(), rawIndices.size());

    // Parse raw vertices for blend indices:
    std::set<char> blendIndices;
    for (int i=0; i<numVerts; ++i) {
        auto offset = VertexLayout::Size * i + VertexLayout::BlendIndexOffset0;
        blendIndices.insert(rawVertices[offset]);
    }
    // Populate selector:
    for (auto blendIndex: blendIndices)
        selector->addItem(QString::number(blendIndex));
    selector->setCurrentRow(0);

    // Forward raw geometry:
    openGLWidget->initGeometry(rawVertices, rawIndices);
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**BoneShaderTest.pro**:

```
QT       += core gui opengl
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = BoneShaderTest
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    openglwidget.cpp
HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \
    openglwidget.h
LIBS += opengl32.lib
# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

[The raw mesh data at tinyupload.com](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=62290867171005994536)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look through, and not a lot seems wrong. The only thing that *might* be an issue is the call to:

```
program.setAttributeBuffer(blend0Location,
                           GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                           VertexLayout::BlendIndexOffset0,
                           1,
                           VertexLayout::Size);
```

If you are specifying an unsigned integer type for the blend index, then make sure you are doing so with: glVertexArrayAttrib**I**Format (and not glVertexArrayAttribFormat). But then again, if it's working for the case when the index is zero, it kinda indicates something is going wrong when setting the uniform index value.

When tracking down stuff like this, usually it's a good idea to hook into the OpenGL debug API to get it to output the current errors. At worst, you can always fall back to the old glGetError approach, and wrap all calls into GL with a simple check macro to see if any errors are occurring.

```
inline void checkGlError(const char* const file, const char* const op, int line)
{
  switch(glGetError())
  {
  case GL_NO_ERROR:  return;
  case GL_INVALID_ENUM: fprintf(stderr, "file: %s\n\t%s: line %d: GL_INVALID_ENUM\n", file, op, line); break;
  case GL_INVALID_VALUE: fprintf(stderr, "file: %s\n\t%s: line %d: GL_INVALID_VALUE\n", file, op, line); break;
  case GL_INVALID_OPERATION: fprintf(stderr, "file: %s\n\t%s: line %d: GL_INVALID_OPERATION\n", file, op, line); break;
  case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: fprintf(stderr, "file: %s\n\t%s: line %d: GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION\n", file, op, line); break;
  case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY: fprintf(stderr, "file: %s\n\t%s: line %d: GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY\n", file, op, line); break;
  default: fprintf(stderr, "file: %s\n\t%s: line %d: unknown Gl error\n", file, op, line); break;
  }
}

#define CHECK_GL_ERROR(X) X; checkGlError(__FILE__, #X, __LINE__);
```

Comment: Your hint about the integer version glVertexArrayAttribIFormat was the first clue. The second clue was your comment about something going wrong setting the uniform value, which led to a more careful look at the types in the original shaders, where there were serious mistakes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The hints given by robthebloke led to the solution. Two changes were necessary.

First, it was necessary to use `glVertexAttribIPointer` to handle integer type correctly:

```
program.setAttributeBuffer(blend0Location,
                           GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                           VertexLayout::BlendIndexOffset0,
                           1,
                           VertexLayout::Size);
```

was replaced with:

```
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_4_0_Core>

auto fun = new QOpenGLFunctions_4_0_Core();
fun->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
fun->glVertexAttribIPointer(blend0Location, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                       VertexLayout::Size, reinterpret_cast<const void*>(qintptr(VertexLayout::BlendIndexOffset0)));
```

Secondly, it was necessary to update the shaders.  The vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
in vec4 a_position;
in int a_blend0;
flat out int v_blend0;
uniform mat4 mvp_matrix;
void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp_matrix * a_position;
    v_blend0 = a_blend0;
}
```

and the fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
flat in int v_blend0;
out vec4 fragmentColor;
uniform int boneToColor;
void main() {
    if (v_blend0 == boneToColor)
        fragmentColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    else
        fragmentColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```